# What free accurate de-duplicator, with image preview, can simultaneously delete multiple duplicate images on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, gratis, photography

Please reply only if your recommendation fulfills ALL FIVE criteria. Kindly recommend

1. free
2. accurate de-duplication
3. Windows 10 software that
4. Can preview both the older and new duplicates
5. Can delete multiple duplicates simultaneously. Awesome Duplicate Photo Finder lacks property #5.

Comment: I use Geeqie http://www.geeqie.org/ Not sure if it has #3, so this may be an answer for people who does not have that restriction.

Comment: If you're not "sure if it has #3", then this doesn't answer my question. Geeqie doesn't appear to run on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest using [visipics](http://www.visipics.info/)

Is completely free, lets you preview and compare duplicates, and can delete multiple duplicates simultaneously letting you select either the images to be deleted or the one that should stay, whatever you prefer. Should run on Windows 10. When run on a folder it even groups the files into similar pictures, with a customizable threshold of similarity.