# What accurate de-duplicator, with image preview and similarity score, simultaneously deletes multiple images on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, photography

Please reply only if your recommendation fulfills ALL FIVE criteria, and clarify if it's free or paid. Of course I prefer free software! Kindly recommend

1. accurate de-duplication
2. Windows 10 software that
3. Can preview both the older and new duplicates
4. Can delete multiple duplicates simultaneously. Awesome Duplicate Photo Finder lacks property #5.
5. distinguishes similar, but non-identical, pictures. And indicates the similarity as a percentage. [visipics](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/78023/71469) doesn't do so.

Comment: This doesn't duplicate the linked post,, because here the software can be paid, and because that post doesn't have criterion 5.

Comment: Then the proper way to do it is to update your original question instead of duplicate it with minor differences.

Comment: This is essentially a minor edit of your existing question: [What free accurate de-duplicator, with image preview, can simultaneously delete multiple duplicate images on Windows 10?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/77968/38103)

Comment: @MichaelC But then that answer wouldn't apply.

Comment: Then downvote the answer, since it doesn't apply to that question as now worded (assuming you are correct that the suggested app doesn't work with Wondows10). If you edit the question it will show as recently active and may attract more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about **AntiDupl**? It's free.

https://github.com/ermig1979/AntiDupl

[image]

> It can find and display duplicate images in the main graphic formats: JPEG, GIF, TIFF, BMP, PNG, EMF, WMF, EXIF, ICON, JP2, PSD, DDS and TGA. The comparison is based on the contents of the files, so the program can find not only almost identical, but similar images. In addition, the program can find images with some types of defects.

> AntiDupl.NET program is free and open-source software. It is simple to use, has high speed and accuracy of work, supports Russian and English interface.

Answer (score 0):

I use Find.Same.Images.OK which I believe should do what you expect. Please try as your expectation might be different from my interpretation. The software is freeware. Get it from https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Find.Same.Images.OK